# Programming Combination Math (Using Python)

Tags: python, math, combinations

[Traffic map Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMQQE.jpg)

Traffic map contains straight segments of two types. The ones with arrows can only go one way in the direction of the arrow and those without arrows can go in two directions. Calculate the number of ways to go from A to B without any repeated lines?

With this math problem, how to solve it ? I don't know what to do right now !

Comment: Seems like the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319245/number-of-possibilities-to-cross-a-hexagonal-lattice

Answer (score 0):

It's a graph theory problem, in your problem try to consider every junction as a node and the segments as the edges of the graph, generally your graph is a directed-graph, when the segments that have two directions are just two edges from the same rwo nodes.

The algorithm you need to implement is DFS (Depth First Traversal).

The idea is as following:

1. Start the DFS traversal from source.
2. Keep storing the visited vertices in an array or HashMap say ‘path[]’.
3. If the destination vertex is reached, print contents of path[].
4. The important thing is to mark current vertices in the path[] as visited also so that the traversal doesn’t go in a cycle.